# Kubernetes ingress gives 502 Bad Gateway even if Pod log says 200 response (on specific usecase)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

In general GET & POST are working.
But POST to a specific use case gives response code 502, even if the Pod log says response code 200. I don't know how to further debug that.

**Expected behavior**

```
Request URL: https://example.foo/api/rpc/request-password-reset
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
```

Pod log

```
26/Oct/2023:07:35:22 +0000 "POST /api/rpc/request-password-reset" 200
```

**Expected behavior (login with invalid credentials)**

```
Request URL: https://example.foo/api/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
```

Pod log

```
26/Oct/2023:07:59:41 +0000 "POST /api/login" 401
```

**Non expected behavior (login with valid credentials)**

```
Request URL: https://example.foo/api/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 502 Bad Gateway
```

Pod log

```
26/Oct/2023:07:40:15 +0000 "POST /api/login" 200
```

Here you can see the mismatching response codes.
I also disabled the setting of a cookie which would happen, still the code mismatch happens.
The rest of the log doesn't show any critical or error event.

This is the ingress

```yaml
# see https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/fcgi-services/

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
data:
  SCRIPT_FILENAME: "/home/api/public/index.php"

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "FCGI"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-index: "index.php"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-params-configmap: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: {{ .Values.host }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .Release.Name }}
                port:
                  name: fastcgi
```

Any ideas how to further debug, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add annotation like below in nginx yaml file.

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "128k"

and you also should change request header size of Load Balancer provieded by cloud plaform like above size.